# How to enable local code while using a conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

How do I import local code while using a conda environment?

I have some code in some location like C:\Users\me\Code\mycode\, and that directory is in my path variable. From my base python environment I can import it:

```
> python --version
  Python 3.7.3
> python
>>> import mycode
>>> #worked
```

But if I active a conda environment, I can no longer access my code.

```
> conda activate myenv
(myenv) > python
>>> import mycode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mycode'
```

Is there a way to tell conda to enable regions included in the path variable, or to easily include other local code into the environment?

Comment: "*that directory is in my path*" please be specific. Does this mean literally `PATH`? or are you talking about `PYTHONPATH`? Works fine with `PYTHONPATH` or being in the working directory.

Comment: I literally mean PATH

Comment: I tried adding the same directory to PYTHONPATH, and the problem remains unchanged. The mycode package uses a regular namespace with __init__.py files. If I  make mycode.py file then conda-python finds it. So this seems to be a problem with regular vs namespace packages.

Comment: If the `__init__.py` is in `C:\Users\me\Code\mycode`, then you would add `C:\Users\me\Code` to `PYTHONPATH` and this will let you run `import mycode`.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses [the `PYTHONPATH` variable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to populate paths where it searches for modules. You can inspect where Python is searching using `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`.

To use code in a folder like `C:\Users\me\Code\mycode`, one would set `PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\me\Code`. This presumes an `__init__.py` is present in the `mycode/` directory.

I'd recommend using this only sparingly. It sort of violates the isolation that Conda envs are trying to achieve. Personally, I would avoid setting this variable at a global level and instead only set it at the env level. This can be done either [with activation hooks](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables), or, since Conda v4.8, set it at the commandline with [the `conda env config vars` command](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables).